# Automapper Map Property as Collection

Tags: automapper

I need to map **ICustomerAddresses** to my own custom object **Address**, or **List < Address >**. How can I use automapper to indicate that the property Customer.ICustomerAddresses maps to my custom Address?

To, illustrate, I have a an interface that has its properties listed like this:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    ICustomerAddresses Addresses;
}
```

In this case, ICustomerAddresses is a collection of ICustomerAddress. However, ICustomerAddress is not a simple IEnumerable, it contains properties that contain the collection, like this:

```
public interface ICustomerAddresses : IBusinessObjectCollection
  {
    ICustomerAddress this[int nIndex] { get; }

    ICustomerAddress CreateNew();

    ICustomerAddress AddNew();

  }
```

Automapper cannot figure out on its own that **ICustomerAddresses** is really just a collection of **ICustomerAddress**, so how do I tell it that's the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A custom type converter should work fine.  Here's a quick example (thrown together -- not tested).  Also, I added a "Length" property to the `ICustomerAddresses` so I knew how many to loop through:

```
public class AddressConverter : TypeConverter<ICustomerAddresses, IList<Address>>
{
    protected override IList<Address> ConvertCore(ICustomerAddresses source)
    {
        var addresses = new List<Address>();
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            var addr = source[i];
            addresses.Add(new Address
                            {
                                Addr1 = addr.Addr1, 
                                Zip = addr.Zip
                            });
        }

        return addresses;
    }
}
```

And you could probably utilize Automapper inside the loop too to convert the `ICustomerAddress` to an `Address` instead of doing it manually like I did.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give this a shot and get back to you.